# Google Analytics, list specific pages for report

Tags: statistics, analytics

We have a large website, and we have special product department that needs to receive specific reports from google analytics.

For example, we have some products located in random URLs:

example.com/en/product-1

example.com/en/product-156

example.com/en/your-table

example.com/fr/merci

example.com/en/product-11

example.com/fr/paris-eifel

(..more that 200 products)

Is there a feature inside google analytics where can I add all these pages manually to get report only for these pages?

Thank you!

Comment: P.S. i've tried to add report in Behaviour -> Pages, and specifying filters, but it's didn't do the trick. We have many other pages with similar URLS that must not be in that report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex filter on the Behavior -> pages page.

In there you can use `example.com/\w{2}/.*$` for example to get all the links you listed in your post.

[image]

The screenshot is in dutch, but it should look the same for you.

Comment: This is a great start... but this only works for one link? If i want to include 3 specific pages, the operator is an AND operator and won't work?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by adding a new segment with the URLs I wanted.

[image: New Segment]

Comment: This works okay, but it seems to be limited to just 20 pages.